# Stop service on application kill

Tags: android, service

I am working on an application which tracks user's movement within a geofence while the application is running. The main activity(M) starts and binds to the GeofenceService(S) which then counts number of steps taken by the user within the specified geofence.

I want the service to be destroyed as soon as the user moves out of the geofence or when the application is killed. To stop the service when the application is killed, I simply unbind the service and then call `stopservice()` on S.

Here goes the code in the main activity for destroying S.

```
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy of main activity");
    if(isGeofenceBound){
        Log.d(TAG, "unbinding geofence service");
        unbindService(mGeofenceConnection);
        isGeofenceBound = false;
    }
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GeofenceService.class));
    Log.d(TAG, "after calling stop service on geofenceservice in main activity");
}
```

And here goes the `onDestroy()` method of S.

```
 public void onDestroy(){

    if(mBound){
        unbindService(mStepConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    stopPedometerService();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "before super onDestroy of geofence service");
    stopSelf();

    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "After super onDestroy of geofence service");
}
```

And here's the manifest code for the service

```
<service android:name=".geofencing.GeofenceService"
             android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```

Upon clearing the application from the android recents list, I get all the log statements mentioned in the code above in the android studio monitor, however the service seems to stay alive because on the application restart, its variables states are preserved from the last start.

Comment: "its variables states are preserved from the last start" -- what variable states? Where are these variables declared? Are they regular fields or `static` fields?

Comment: The variables are declared in the Geofence service. They are static variables.

Comment: I have noticed that the main activity does not call its `onDestroy()` method when I close the application without starting the Geofence `service`,  however the `onDestroy()` method does get called when the application is closed after starting the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its variables states are preserved from the last start.

[According to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294763/prevent-stopped-service-from-responding-to-broadcasts?noredirect=1#comment73656425_43294763), those are `static` fields. Such `static` fields live for the life of the process. The fact that your service is being destroyed has no immediate impact on your process. If you start your service again while the process is still around, those `static` fields will have whatever values they used to have.

Remove the `static` keyword from those fields if you do not want this behavior.

Comment: Okay I see now how making the fields non static would help me, but the service is also listening to GPS state change broadcasts and I do not wish the service to respond to such broadcasts when the application is not running.

Comment: @forcehandler: "but the service is also listening to GPS state change broadcasts" -- I do not see any code in your question related to broadcasts.